# Puppeteer - using '--allow-file-access-from-files' to load a local file through XMLHttpRequest is not working

Tags: javascript, chromium, puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use a local file in Headless Chromium started through Puppeteer.

I always run into the following error:

```
'Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https'
```

I did attempt to set `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

It can be reproduced as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({headless:true,args:['--allow-file-access-from-files']}).then(
  async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent('<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><div>A page</div></body></html>');
    await page.addScriptTag({url:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"});
    await page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
    await page.evaluate (() => {
      $.get('file:///..../cors.js')
        .done(
           _ => console.log('done')
        ).fail(
          e => console.log('fail:'+JSON.stringify(e))
        );
    });
  await browser.close();
  }
);
```

Looking at the running processes, it does look like Chromium was started with the option.

All tips warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to load your local file from the Page DOM Environment using [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), which will not work because it is a violation of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

The Chromium flag [`--allow-file-access-from-files`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) is described below:

> By default, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. This is an override for developers who need the old behavior for testing.

This flag does not apply to your scenario.

You can use the Node.js function [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) instead to obtain the content of your file and pass it to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const file_path = '/..../cors.js';
const file_content = fs.existsSync(file_path) ? fs.readFileSync(file_path, 'utf8') : '';

await page.evaluate(file_content => {
  console.log(file_content);
}, file_content);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the actual code as you suggest. But you did point me in the right direction. Disabling cors check when launching chromium makes it work for me. Tx!